Selenium Python Chrome Blocking Download
I've been trying to download a pdf file from the following website:
http://www.cub.org.br/cub-m2-estadual/CE/
The problem is that when I click "Gerar Relatório em PDF" ("Generate PDF Report" in English), the Chrome raises a message to me saying that the download was blocked because the file isn't trustable. I've tried many thing in Selenium Python in order to bypass this security message. Yet, I'm still getting this "error".
Below is my code:
`
# Pasta Padrão
download_dir = os.getcwd()
# Instância Chrome Options
chrome_options = Options()

# Configurando Chrome Para Permitir Dowload do PDF
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")

# Pasta Download
prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
    "download.open_pdf_in_system_reader": False,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

# Instância Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,
                          options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

# Acessando Site
driver.get('http://www.cub.org.br/cub-m2-estadual/CE/')
time.sleep(2)

# Verifica Anos Disponíveis
# Na Lista Suspensa
lista_suspensa = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ano'))
opcoes_lista_suspensa = [item.text for item in lista_suspensa.options]

# Seleciona Primeiro Elemento da Lista
# Que é o Ano Mais Recente
lista_suspensa.select_by_value(opcoes_lista_suspensa[0])

# Clicando Baixar Relatório
download_file_xpath = '//*[@id="wrapper"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/input[2]'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, download_file_xpath).click()

`

Yeah! I tried both. Did not worked yet

I believe ChromeDriver behavior has changed some time ago. Below are the options/prefs you need to get it working:
chrome_options.add_argument("--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://www.cub.org.br")

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
}

